# UISearchBar crashing when touched

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar.  It works perfectly until I search once and it gives me a result, if I then search again, it crashes when I select it.

I have this method which it crashes at.  Any ideas?

```
[self.billingSearchPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:[self.billingSearchBar bounds] inView:self.billingSearchBar permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that you have not prematurely released billingSearchPopoverController.

Comment: I don't get any console log even though I have NSZombies on.  I get this in the stack trace though `0x00003c8f _Z16TerminateHandlerv + 34`

Comment: I'm only releasing `billingSearchPopoverController` in dealloc.

Comment: Hmmm.. So you get nothing in console on the crash. Without seeing more code, my recommendation would be for you to use breakpoints and step through the app. Unless you are running on a device, in which case I would take a look at your memory footprint.

Comment: I've setup breakpoints.  That is how I narrowed it down to the one line I posted in the question.

Comment: Ah ok. The only other thing I can think is that something is happening to you search bar after first search. Try changing this piece "[self.billingSearchBar bounds]" to [self.view frame]. That wil not produced the desired effect of course, but it will help you narrow down your crash; if it crashes you know the issue is with the search bar.

Comment: So it is not crashing anymore when I use `[self.view frame]`.  So do you know what the issue may be?

Comment: It is likely that your billingSearchBar is being deallocated somewhere, so the frame message is crashing. Look at your memory footprint. I hope that helps

Comment: `billingSearchBar` is only being set to nil in viewDidUnload and releaesed in dealloc.  It is being set as first responder and resigned in other places though.  That is pretty much it.

Comment: If you are not releasing it but it seems like it is getting blown away, check for memory warnings.  Also, it's silly but make sure you are consistant with self.searBar and searchBar that can cause problems. I can't specifically tell you what to do, since I have not seen all the code or run your app, but I do believe that the memory analysis and profiling tools included with XCode are worth a look in this case. Sorry but I don't have info to be more specific.